# Vue packages version mismatch on Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to upgrade from Vue 2 version to vue 3, my project has Nuxt.js framework.

I put this command to upgrade : `vue add vue-next`, and upgrade has been successful. but when I try to execute project appear the next error :

```
Vue packages version mismatch:
  
  - vue@3.0.7
  - vue-server-renderer@2.6.12
  
  This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use SSR with Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64239478/how-to-use-ssr-with-vue-3)

Answer (score 0):

That problem happened to me after an update. This is what worked for me.

1. delete the project's node_modules folder
2. delete the package-lock.json file
3. npm i

Solution found here https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6823

see post from "daniplaninc"

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are mentioning here comes from the fact that Nuxt 3 hasn't been released yet : it still doesn't support Vue 3, hence your application won't compile with vue 3...

The release is planned for Midsummer 2022 : https://v3.nuxtjs.org/community/roadmap/

I am waiting for this version too so I hope it will be released soon !