# Vue packages version mismatch error while installing Nuxt.js: How to resolve?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, dependency-management, nuxtjs3, vue-server-renderer

I am trying to install Nuxt.js v3.4.2 using the command npx nuxt init nuxt3-demo and then running npm install. However, I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: Vue packages version mismatch:
- vue@3.2.40
- vue-server-renderer@2.7.10
This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
```

I have tried updating the 'vue' package, but it did not solve the issue. My package.json file looks like this:

```
  {
    "name": "nuxt-app",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "build": "nuxt build",
      "dev": "nuxt dev",
      "generate": "nuxt generate",
      "preview": "nuxt preview",
      "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@types/node": "^18",
      "nuxt": "^3.4.2"
    }
  }
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this error?

Comment: What happens when you use `npx nuxi upgrade` (or `npx nuxi upgrade --force`) ?

Comment: Nothing happens, it throws the same ERROR: Vue packages version mismatch

Comment: I had this error and another error related to node-gyp during package installation (npm install). I ended up installing Visual Studio with the `Desktop development with c++` option checked and the errors disappeared!

Comment: what does it say when you run `npx nuxi info`?

Comment: At what point do you get the error? I ran `npx nuxt init nuxt3-demo` then `pnpm install` then `pnpm dev` and it worked fine with no issues. It installed `nuxt@3.4.3`

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you can:

1 -  try `npm install` after removing the "node_modules" folder and the "package-lock.json" file.

2 - Try `yarn install`.

3 - Try again with the new version, v3.4.3.

I edited this because, as Wongjn said, I asked for clarification. However, providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice, given the nature of the problem and how hard replicating the issue is.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34334192)

Comment: The question requested a solution, which I gave. Based on my experience, since I could not replicate the issue. But you were right, and I will avoid asking for clarification in answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because vue-server-renderer is only for Vue2 and not for Vue3. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64239478/how-to-use-ssr-with-vue-3-vue-packages-version-mismatch#:%7E:text=Vue-server-renderer%20can%20only%20be%20used%20with%20vue%20version,you%20now%20just%20have%20to%20use%20vue%27s%20createSSRApp.)

Just remove the package `vue-server-renderer`, you'll get SSR features from [nuxt](https://nuxt.new).

```
npm remove vue-server-renderer
```

Then, delete your `node_modules` folder, then try again: `npx nuxt init nuxt3-demo`.